# /states/louisiana/ or just /louisiana/ in the URL path for SEO of a restaurant site based on WordPress?

Tags: seo, wordpress, tags, categories

Hoping to find a site structuring best practice for a Wordpress site that features restaurants by state, that is still readable enough to Google's bots so as to not be detrimental to the SEO.

Is it better for SEO to use the category base "states"
Example –
`example.com/states/louisiana/restaurant-name` 
or just
 `example.com/louisiana/restaurant-name`

If I include the base, should I make a page with all of the states listed? At that point does it make more sense to do "states" as a parent category with each state as a child?

I know this seems really simple at first glance, I just want to make sure I'm heading in the right direction – what do you think?

Comment: The directories in the URL path don't matter much for SEO at all these days.  Either way could have fine SEO.  What would your users find most natural and easiest to use?